# Как поменять местами объекты в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть заполненный массив объектов

```
MyObject[] array = new MyObject[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    array[i] = new MyObject();
}
```

Программа должна в цикле (в зависимости от логики) часто менять местами объекты находящиеся в элементах массива(не создавая при этом новых объектов). Я создаю один объект MyObject, по-порядку копирую в него значения всех полей первого объекта(для временного хранения). После этого из второго объекта в первый копирую значения всех полей. А потом из временного объекта копирую значения полей во второй объект. Получается довольно длинный код. Может быть есть более короткий и быстрый способ? Подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объекты - это ссылки. Поэтому достаточно сделать так

```java
MyObject tmp = array[0];
array[0] = array[1];
array[1] = tmp;
```